# ansible registering variables and loops

Tags: loops, ansible

I'm new to ansible so bear with me

I need to create a playbook that reads a file and retrieve a list of servers, then connects to each node and retrieves the value of a file in each (env), then puts together a compiled txt with the information:

- node1 - version - env
- node2 - version - env
- node3 - version - env

the problem resides when I have to put everything together

```yaml
- name: check remote file
  remote_user: user
  shell: cat /remote/file
  register: env

- name: get version
  shell: cat /local/file | -f3 | sort | uniq
  register: vers
  delegate_to: localhost

- name: save results
  shell: echo NODE {{ hostz.stdout_lines }} VERSION {{ vers.stdout_lines }}  ENVIRONMENT {{ env.stdout_lines }} >> /home/user/test.csv
  delegate_to: localhost
```

as you can imagine, it's doing a loop per task, so I end up with a file with all the hosts, then all the versions and all the environments, which makes no sense whatsoever, what do you think would be the best way of putting this together?

I'm basically trying to do a for hosts in $hostz; do ...

Answer (score 0):

For example, the inventory below

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
[my_group]
test_01
test_02
test_03
```

this playbook

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: my_group
  tasks:
    - shell: 'cat /etc/passwd| wc -l'
      register: env

    - shell: 'cat /etc/passwd| wc -l'
      register: vers
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
      
    - template:
        src: test.csv.j2
        dest: test.csv
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

and this template

```yaml
shell> cat test.csv.j2
{% for host in groups.my_group %}
NODE {{ host }} VERSION {{ vers.stdout|trim }} ENVIRONMENT {{ hostvars[host]['env']['stdout']|trim }}
{% endfor %}
```

give

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yml 

PLAY [my_group] ************************************************************

TASK [shell] ***************************************************************
changed: [test_01]
changed: [test_03]
changed: [test_02]

TASK [shell] ***************************************************************
changed: [test_01 -> localhost]

TASK [template] ************************************************************
changed: [test_01 -> localhost]

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************
test_01: ok=3 changed=3 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=0 rescued=0 ignored=0   
test_02: ok=1 changed=1 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=0 rescued=0 ignored=0   
test_03: ok=1 changed=1 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=0 rescued=0 ignored=0
```

```yaml
shell> cat test.csv
NODE test_01 VERSION 55 ENVIRONMENT 37
NODE test_02 VERSION 55 ENVIRONMENT 31
NODE test_03 VERSION 55 ENVIRONMENT 29
```